How to download YouTube videos using pydub?
Changes in Youtube in 2024 caused you-get and pydub to not operate smoothly.
How to download YouTube videos using pydub?
(I just want to share a solution.)

First of all, some people say that pydub is no longer maintained. Please use pytubefix instead.
You can try to download the highest quality
from pytubefiximport YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX')
yt.streams.filter().get_highest_resolution().download(filename='XXX.mp4')

Or try to download the specified image quality
yt.streams.filter().get_by_resolution('360p').download(filename='XXX.mp4')

Of course, you can also check if there are better quality images available for download:
for stream in yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4'):
    fps = getattr(stream, 'fps', 'N/A') # Use getattr to avoid AttributeError and return 'N/A' if there is no fps attribute
    stream_type = 'Progressive' if getattr(stream, 'is_progressive', False) else 'Adaptive'
    print(f"Resolution: {stream.resolution}, FPS: {fps}, Mime Type: {stream.mime_type},Stream Type: {stream_type}")

Because I found that when the image quality is 1080p or above, many YouTube are Adaptive, which requires audio and video to be downloaded separately and then merged, so I wrote a semi-finished product. The current version directly provides downloading and merging of the highest image quality.
https://github.com/e950280/U2_downloader
BTW
pip install ffmpeg,pytubefix
